# Apache <VirtualHost> tag, do NOT redirect if client's IP = x... how to do that?

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, virtualhost, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

so I couldn't find an answer to this question anywhere...
I am redirecting my clients from http to https when they're using http by having this in my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName futurelegendonline.net
   Redirect permanent / https://futurelegendonline.net/
</VirtualHost>
```

But I want to make it only redirect people that are using my domain address (futurelegendonline.net). So basically, this does the job for me but I **don't** want this to work when people use the IP itself (199.168.117.73). Is there any any way to do this? Or alternatively, just make an exception to not redirect certain client IPs somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way to do what you are asking is to create two separate `VirtualHost` in your configuration.

The first `VirtualHost` will define the default virtual host, which will be used to server all clients specifying a hostname unknown to the server.

If you are using a distribution where the convention is to put all `VirtualHost` in a single configuration file, it could look roughly like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName 199.168.117.73
   DocumentRoot /var/www/default
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName futurelegendonline.net
   Redirect permanent / https://futurelegendonline.net/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the job. Is there a way to redirect everyone from futurelegendonline.net to https as it is, but in exception to a few client ips?

Comment: @FightRay I cannot think of any very simple solution for that. Probably [mod_rewrite](http://serverfault.com/q/214512/214507) can do it by using `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Enclose the Redirect in an <If></If> that uses a condition such that the redirect applies only when %{REMOTE_ADDR} is not the excepted IP address. The configuration in the answer will allow ANY ip address that addresses the server by ip address to come in on http

Comment: @Colt Thanks for the answer, I have a vague idea of how to do this thanks to your explanation, but I'll be happy to be provided with a simple example to it if possible, just to make sure.

Comment: Perhaps something like `<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'"> Redirect permanent / https://futurelegendonline.net </If>`